# yii ajaxSubmitButton blocks html5 validation

Tags: jquery, html, forms, yii

I have a form where I used ajaxSubmitButton to submit that form. But Yii generates `return false` at the end of jQuery that handles ajax, so automatic HTML5 validation is not working anymore. (for example input type=number accepts letters too) Any Idea how to solve it?

Try to enter any letters to the field and submit form in the following demos and you will see what I mean:

[DEMO without ajaxSubmitButton](http://jsfiddle.net/DCUYy/17/)

[DEMO with simple ajaxSubmitButton](http://jsfiddle.net/UNSt9/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Try to catch the submit event of the form instead

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('body').on('submit','form',function() {
              jQuery.ajax({'type':'POST'});
         return false;
    });
});
```

Not sure if it would have other implications.

Comment: Problem is that all the jQuery code is automatically generated by Yii framework, so I can't really change it